# Why do some sites notify me of favourite changes while others don't?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, favorites-notifications, preferences

Also, what happened to [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications/57550#57550)? It doesn't even appear on MSO any more, unless I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: the handling of favorites is in a bit of flux at the moment, but we aren't done with it.